# Sitecore in-place upgrade best approach suggestions

Tags: sitecore-client, upgrade

We are planing to upgrade Sitecore 9.3 to 10.3 and the approach we have chosen is an in-place upgrade (Update Sitecore on existing 9.3 instance). The 9.3 application is running in Azure. Could some one please best approach to complete the upgrade.

Regards,
Reddy.

Comment: Best approach questions, by their nature are opinion based and not right for SSE. Please ask the question in the Sitecore Slack channels for a discussion on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to follow Sitecore's [official guide to upgrade](https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/%7E/media/E41E93BF069242BEABC7F2669C7EFB1E.ashx?date=20210209T121656).

This guide applies to `on-premise` version.

Your upgrade execution plan can be like this. And you can follow upgrade details from above document.

- You can start upgrade locally and manage it differently, may be in a separate repo.
- And once you complete upgrade locally, you can deploy it to various environments for quality check. (You can procure your Azure resource at this stage)
- Since your current setup is on Azure, you can create a parallel setup for upgrade site and once it is ready to launch, just switch the DNS.

I hope this helps.

Comment: am looking for upgradation on existing instance .we are not planning to setup new environment and we planning to use existing instance and top of that we are planning to do upgradation

Comment: If you upgrade existing instance, there will be downtime. If your client is okay with it then it's doable.

Answer (score 1):

To find the complete details with the steps Sitecore provides Sitecore [SC-XP-10.3.1-Update_Installation_Guide-en_v2](https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/%7E/media/0A27A888C57C42ACB078D64A0D2456BD.ashx?date=20231010T175250) to update your `Sitecore XP solution to the latest update release`. You can refer to this PDF file and start working on the upgrade.

The main steps would be:

1. Upgrade the framework and Database
2. Upgrade the Search mechanism in Sitecore SOLR
3. Upgrade any custom or existing modules
4. Deploy application on Sitecore Managed Cloud Service PaaS

For the detailed description and steps refer to the blog post: [Upgrade Sitecore Project to the latest release](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2022/11/upgrade-sitecore-project-to-version-102.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore provides detailed documentation for upgrading from one version to another. Here are some simplified steps you may refer to.

- Take backups of your Sitecore databases, content, and codebase.
- Follow the instructions in the Sitecore upgrade guide to upgrade databases using the Sitecore Update Installation Wizard (UIW) or Sitecore Azure Toolkit.
- Replace your Sitecore 9.3 files with Sitecore 10.3 files in your solution.
- Update any custom code, modules, or integrations to be compatible with Sitecore 10.3.
- Update configuration files such as web.config, ConnectionStrings.config, and any custom configuration files to match the changes introduced in Sitecore 10.3.
- Finally, Perform thorough testing of the upgraded environment to ensure all functionalities are working correctly.

And follow the Sitecore upgrade guide for more reference.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/installation-and-upgrade-guides

Hope this helps.